# Excel VBA - Issues with For Each Loop with an Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, for-loop, foreach

Hoping I can find some help with this one.  I am pulling in information from Excel from 2 columns (Hostname, IP).  The declarations of importance are

```
Dim HWSWArray() As Variant
Dim v As Variant.
```

My HWSWArray is loaded and as an example I have HWSWArray(0)(0) -> Hostname and HWSWArray(0)(1) -> IP

I want to loop through these and do an external comparison to another string so I have my loop written as such

```
For Each v In HWSWArray         
        If v(0) = POAMHost Then
           DoThings
        ElseIf v(1) = POAMHost Then
           Do Things
        End If
 Next
```

I am getting a type mismatch as soon as it evaluates the first if statement.  I am confused because they are both variants v and HWSWArray and shouldn't v as a variant match whatever type it is matching against?

Maybe I am missing the forest for the trees?  I can post the full code if necessary but will need to redact some stuff.

To add some more information with code that I can easily share, I have done something similar in the past that has worked and I cant tell what the difference is.  I will look at implementing your suggestions for the For i loop if I can't get this to work but I am trying to see why it wont work in its current capacity.

```
    'Load BArray
    Do While Counter <> B1930Rows + 1

    IPCell = Assets.Range("X" & Counter)
    hostCell = Assets.Range("W" & Counter)


    If IsEmpty(Assets.Range("W" & Counter)) = True And IsEmpty(Assets.Range("X" & Counter)) = True Then
        Counter = Counter + 1

    ElseIf IsEmpty(Assets.Range("W" & Counter)) = True And IsEmpty(Assets.Range("X" & Counter)) = False Then
        BArray(i) = Array("Null", UCase(IPCell))
        i = i + 1
        Counter = Counter + 1

    ElseIf IsEmpty(Assets.Range("W" & Counter)) = False And IsEmpty(Assets.Range("X" & Counter)) = True Then
        BArray(i) = Array(UCase(hostCell), "Null")
        i = i + 1
        Counter = Counter + 1

    ElseIf IsEmpty(Assets.Range("W" & Counter)) = False And IsEmpty(Assets.Range("X" & Counter)) = False Then
        BArray(i) = Array(UCase(IPCell), UCase(hostCell))
        i = i + 1
        Counter = Counter + 1

    Else
        Counter = Counter + 1
    End If

Loop

'MsgBox ("Here")
'Setting up script to handle the POAM Analysis Portion
Counter = 2

Dim statusCell As String
'Dim hostCell As String

Do While Counter <> POAMRows + 1

    statusCell = POAM.Range("M" & Counter)
    hostCell = POAM.Range("AE" & Counter)

    If statusCell = "Ongoing" Then

        For Each v In BArray

            If v(0) = hostCell Then
                Output.Range("A" & SummaryCounter) = POAM.Range("A" & Counter)
                Output.Range("B" & SummaryCounter) = POAM.Range("C" & Counter)
                Output.Range("C" & SummaryCounter) = POAM.Range("D" & Counter)
                Output.Range("D" & SummaryCounter) = POAM.Range("E" & Counter)
                Output.Range("E" & SummaryCounter) = POAM.Range("F" & Counter)
                Output.Range("F" & SummaryCounter) = POAM.Range("G" & Counter)
                Output.Range("G" & SummaryCounter) = POAM.Range("R" & Counter)
                Output.Range("H" & SummaryCounter) = POAM.Range("V" & Counter)
                Output.Range("I" & SummaryCounter) = POAM.Range("AB" & Counter)
                Output.Range("J" & SummaryCounter) = POAM.Range("AE" & Counter)


                SummaryCounter = SummaryCounter + 1

            ElseIf v(1) = hostCell Then
                Output.Range("A" & SummaryCounter) = POAM.Range("A" & Counter)
                Output.Range("B" & SummaryCounter) = POAM.Range("C" & Counter)
                Output.Range("C" & SummaryCounter) = POAM.Range("D" & Counter)
                Output.Range("D" & SummaryCounter) = POAM.Range("E" & Counter)
                Output.Range("E" & SummaryCounter) = POAM.Range("F" & Counter)
                Output.Range("F" & SummaryCounter) = POAM.Range("G" & Counter)
                Output.Range("G" & SummaryCounter) = POAM.Range("R" & Counter)
                Output.Range("H" & SummaryCounter) = POAM.Range("V" & Counter)
                Output.Range("I" & SummaryCounter) = POAM.Range("AB" & Counter)
                Output.Range("J" & SummaryCounter) = POAM.Range("AE" & Counter)


                SummaryCounter = SummaryCounter + 1
            End If
        Next
        Counter = Counter + 1
    Else
        Counter = Counter + 1
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: Just so you are aware, 'Dim HWSWArray() As Variant' creates an array of variants rather than a variant which can contain an array.  You possibly only need 'Dim HWSWArray As Variant'

Answer (score 0):

`For Each` and multidimensional arrays are tricky. Try this instead:

```
For i = LBound(HWSWArray, 1) To UBound(HWSWArray, 1)
    If HWSWArray(i, 0) = POAMHost Then
        'Do Things
    ElseIf HWSWArray(i, 1) = POAMHost Then
        'Do Things
    End If
Next
```

`LBound` and `UBound` will give to the lower and upper bound for a given dimension, in this case the first.

Comment: I edited my original post can you take another look?

Comment: @SureThing, after reading your update, I would say that my statement on the trickyness with multidimensional arrays  and For Each still stands. Replace HWSWArray with BArray and you're good to go.

Comment: OK I am understanding where you are coming from.  I was an idiot though.  I had the array too large and the part that had the type mismatch was because it was blank.  I had ReDim the array for 3521 values but it only filled 3520 so index 3521 was blank.  Is there any way to troubleshoot that easier?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have equal length columns:

```
Dim HWSWArray() As Variant
HWSWArray = Range(Cells(startrow, startcolumn), Cells(endrow, endcolumn)).value
Dim i As Long
For i = lbound(HWSWArray) to ubound(HWSWArray)
    If HWSWArray(v,1) = POAMHost Then
        'DoThings
    ElseIf HWSWArray(v,2) = POAMHost Then
        'Do other Things
    End If
Next i
```

the lowerbound (typically 0) and upper bound of the `HWSWArray` will be the row counts for the specific column.

Comment: You might have been right on the `1` and `2`, depending on how OP populated `HWSWArray` (sorry about my previous comment). Although the question mentions `(0)(0)` and `(0)(1)` - which makes me believe that HWSWArray is not populated efficiently.

Comment: @BigBen I was actually just correcting that as my initial thought was how `HWSWArray` was being generated, so I went back and specified *how* the array is being generated in my example.

Comment: In fact you are right based on the `HWSWArray = Range(Cells(startrow, startcolumn), Cells(endrow, endcolumn)).value`, so sorry :) Yep.

Comment: I edited my original post can you take another look?

Comment: @SureThing I took a look at your edit and the code appears to use `Do Until` loops, which is very similar to what is being proposed with the `for` loop, where your `Counter` is `i` and instead of needing to iterate it manually the `for` loop iterates i via `next i`.  The other significant difference would be working an the `variant array` rather than referencing a sheet (like in your edit).  I would suggest trying the provided solution and if it works you'd be in a better position.

Comment: OK I am understanding where you are coming from.  I was an idiot though.  I had the array too large and the part that had the type mismatch was because it was blank.  I had ReDim the array for 3521 values but it only filled 3520 so index 3521 was blank.  Is there any way to troubleshoot that easier?

Comment: @SureThing The `lbound()/ubound()` is what resolves that, so you do not index outside of your defined array range.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone looking at this in the future, I had incorrectly specified the dimensions of my array.  I had extended my array to hold 3521 values but when it was loading the array, it only loaded to 3520.

When my code was running, it was comparing a variable to an empty array so I was getting a type mismatch.

I fixed the dimensions and everything worked fine.